# What is the order that Linux's dynamic linker searches paths in?

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking

This is not a duplicate because this is dealing with a peculiarity I noticed when I use `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

To get the paths that the dynamic linker searches in for libraries, I run the command `ldconfig -v | grep -v "^"$'\t' | sed "s/:$//g"`. When `/etc/ld.so.conf` has no paths listed in it. The output from the previous command is

```
/lib
/usr/lib
```

I figured that it searches `/lib` first and then `/usr/lib`. When I add a new path, such as `/usr/local/lib`, to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then remake `/etc/ld.so.cache`, the output from `ldconfig -v | grep -v "^"$'\t' | sed "s/:$//g"` becomes

```
/usr/local/lib
/lib
/usr/lib
```

I find this strange because if I am correct that the order that the listed directories are searched in is from top to bottom, then additional directories are searched before `/lib` and `/usr/lib`. That the additional directories are searched before the trusted directories is not strange on its own, but when `/lib` is searched before `/usr/lib`, that is strange because `/bin` & `/sbin` are searched after `/usr/bin` & `/usr/sbin` in `PATH`.

Even if the paths listed by `ldconfig -v | grep -Ev "^"$'\t' | sed "s/:$//g"` were searched from bottom to top, it would still be a skewed ordering because additional directories would be searched after the trusted ones while `/lib` would be searched after `/usr/lib`.

So, what is the order that `ld.so` searches paths for libraries in? Why is `/lib` searched before `/usr/lib`? If it's not, then why are additional directories searched after `/lib`?

Answer (score 30):

The order is documented in the manual of the dynamic linker, which is [`ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). It is:

1. directories from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`;
2. directories from `/etc/ld.so.conf`;
3. `/lib`;
4. `/usr/lib`.

(I'm simplifying a little, see the manual for the full details.)

The order makes sense when you consider that it's the only way to override a library in a default location with a custom library. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a user setting, it has to come before the others. `/etc/ld.so.conf` is a local setting, it comes before the operating system default. So as a user, if I want to run a program with a different version of a library, I can run the program with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` containing the location of that different library version. And as an administrator, I can put a different version of the library in `/usr/local/lib` and list `/usr/local/lib` in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

Trust doesn't enter into this. Any directory listed on this search path has to be trusted, because any library could end up being loaded from there. In theory, you could list the library names used by all the programs “requiring more trust” on your system and make sure that all these libraries are present in the “most trusted” directories, and then the “less trusted” directories wouldn't be used if they came after the more trusted directories on the search path, except for the programs “requiring less trust”. But that would be extremely fragile. It would also be pretty pointless: if an attacker can inject a value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or an element of `/etc/ld.so.conf`, they surely have a more direct route to executing arbitrary code, such as injecting a value of `PATH`, of `LD_PRELOAD`, etc. Trust in the library load path does matter when execution crosses a trust boundary, i.e. when running a program with additional privileges (e.g. setuid/setgid program, or via `sudo`). What happens in this case is that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is blanked out.

As for `/lib` vs `/usr/lib`, it doesn't matter much: they're provided by the same entity (the operating system) and there shouldn't be a library that's present in both. It makes sense to list `/lib` first because it provides a (very tiny) performance advantage: the most-often-used libraries, especially the libraries used by small basic programs (for which load time is a higher fraction of total running time than large, long-running program), are located in `/lib`.

Comment: If multiple directories are listed in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, what order are they searched in?

Comment: @argentum2f From left to right, same as `PATH`.

Comment: Note, files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` are processed in alphabetical order. So if you want to override a default library path, you may need to either include the path above the statement in the `/etc/ld.so.conf` which sources the other files, or create a lower alpha filename, such as `00-my.conf` to be processed first into the `ld.so` cache.