# De-prioritize ld.conf.so.d library path resolution

Tags: linux, libraries, dynamic-linking, linker, ld

[From a separate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367600/what-is-the-order-that-linuxs-dynamic-linker-searches-paths-in), and other [articles on the subject](https://www.monperrus.net/martin/notes-on-shared-libraries-with-ld), it appears that additional library paths defined by `ld.so.conf.d` will always be resolved (i.e. in the case of a name clash, such as when overriding a system library), **before** any libraries supplied via `/lib` or `/usr/lib`.

Is it possible to, via `ld.so.conf.d` or some other mechanism, to create a system-wide path where libraries can be resolved, but at the lowest/latest possible resolution level? For example, I'd like libraries in `/ParanoidAndroid/` to be resolved, but I'd like that path to be the last place searched for them (i.e. prioritize the libraries in `/lib` and `/usr/lib` over the libraries stored in `/ParanoidAndroid/`), so the lookup order is now:

1. Directories from LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
2. Directories from /etc/ld.so.conf;
3. /lib;
4. /usr/lib.
5. /ParanoidAndroid;

Answer (score 3):

You can list `/lib` and `/usr/lib` explicitly in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or one of the files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, that way directories coming after those two will have lower priority in the search.

Something like this:

```
# contents of /etc/ld.so.conf
/lib
/usr/lib
/ParanoidAndroid
```

Don't forget to:

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

And you can check that with:

```
$ ldconfig -v
```

Then confirm the libraries under `/ParanoidAndroid` come last.

(You might see warnings such as `ldconfig: Path '/lib' given more than once`, but that's probably what you expected anyways, right?)