# ld ignores ld.so.conf

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-library, linker

This is my `/etc/ld.so.conf`

```
/usr/local/lib64
/usr/local/lib
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

The directory `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` contains `mysql-x86_64.conf` which contains only this one line: `/usr/lib64/mysql`

The `/usr/lib64/mysql` directory [listed in the `.conf` file] contains these files:

```
total 45,961,216
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      4,096 Apr 11 17:20 ./
drwxr-xr-x 121 root root     81,920 Mar 30 20:01 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 28,951,398 Dec  9 21:40 libmysqlclient.a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         20 Dec  9 21:56 libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.21*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         25 Dec  9 21:56 libmysqlclient.so.21 -> libmysqlclient.so.21.1.19*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 16,869,104 Dec  9 21:40 libmysqlclient.so.21.1.19*
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     44,910 Dec  9 21:36 libmysqlservices.a
```

Running `ldconfig -p | grep mysql` returns this:

```
    libmysqlclient.so.21 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.21
    libmysqlclient.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so
```

When I try to link a very small MySQL test program I get this error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/9/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
```

Adding `-L/usr/lib64/mysql` to the linker works.

**My question:**

According to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367682/144303) and other documentation found on internet `ldd` is considering the content of the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file - why is in my case the content ignored? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ld.so.conf` is the configuration file for `ld.so`, the runtime dynamic linker.

`ld` ignores it, intentionally. It has its own defaults, supplemented by `-L`. Typically the search path is also determined by the compiler driving it — see `gcc -print-search-dirs` for GCC.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` also only affects `ld.so`, [not `ld`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449063/86440).

See also [what are the executable ELF files respectively for static linker, dynamic linker, loader and dynamic loader?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/476780/86440)